# App to see how my application are using my upload internet bandwith?

Tags: applications, data-transfer

Is there any app to see how my applications are using my upload internet bandwith?

I have an app called [Arq](http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/) which basically uploads data to amazon storage.

The problem is that it took me 10 days to upload 30GB of data. My provided upload speed is around 600KB, then there is problem with this.

I thought of checking if any other app is using my upload internet bandwith. Am I in the right way...?
What do you think, what else can I do?

At first I thought it was a problem related to the app Arq, then I posted this problem in its forum: [post](http://support.haystacksoftware.com/?topic=arq-to-glacier-slooooooow), but as you can see the developer of this app says that there is no problem with the app at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it 600KBps (600 kilobyte per second) or 600Kbps (600 kilobit per second)? For the latter it would take 5 days to upload 30GB with optimum upload speed. You say it took 10 days. I would say that is reasonable. You can use the System Monitor app to monitor network traffic. It doesn't make clear what app is using the network, but it does make clear if upload is only half of what you would expect.

Comment: You are right: it is kilobit. Yes, it took 10 day, but I was working with othe app as well which could be consuming the upload bandwith. Then, I think there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Activity Monitor* program included by default with Mac OS X.  You can find it here:
/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app

After you open the app, select the **Network** tab in the lower third of the window.  This'll show you, in aggregate, the total download and upload bandwidth in use by your computer in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

There are few, one that comes to mind is Rubbernet.

RubberNet monitors bandwidth usage and logs this data.. you can also choose which apps to monitor and which not to. can be found here: https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/rubbernet/id425980801?mt=12

From memory it had a great interface and worked with a very low-resource daemon running in the background.